# Is it possible / How to show the operation's argument description in the WSDL?

Tags: soap, wsdl, documentation, arguments, operation

In my WSDLs I provide some information to the service: The input and output types, the operation descriptions etc. Additionally I would like to provide descriptions / comments to the input arguments and the output. So I want this

```
<message name="myOperationIn">
    <part name="myInput" type="tns:MyInput"/>
</message>
<message name="myOperationOut">
    <part name="return" type="tns:MyOutput"/>
</message>
```

to be extended as follows

```
<message name="myOperationIn">
    <part name="myInput" type="tns:MyInput" description="Lorem ipsum... or defined values only: FOO, BAR, BUZ."/>
</message>
<message name="myOperationOut">
    <part name="return" type="tns:MyOutput" description="Dolor sit amet..."/>
</message>
```

I took a look in [WSDL specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl), but didn't find a solution there. (But maybe I'm simply reading it over?)

Is it possible / How to get the operation's argument description into the WSDL?